# Service Failed to Launch a Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy a CloudFormation template that defines a ECS cluster, service, and task definition. When the service tries to start a task, it gives the following error:

> service ECSService failed to launch a task with (error ECS was unable to assume the role 'arn:aws:iam:::role/ExecutionRole' that was provided for this task. Please verify that the role being passed has the proper trust relationship and permissions and that your IAM user has permissions to pass this role.).

I define the role as:

```
  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: ExecutionRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      Path: /myroles
```

And the service:

```
  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: Cluster
  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn:
      - ExecutionRole
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref SecurityGroup
          Subnets:
            - !Ref PublicSubnet
      ServiceName: ECSService
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: Container
          Image: !Ref TaskImage
      Cpu: .25 vCPU
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      Family: GoCapture
      Memory: 0.5 GB
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RuntimePlatform:
        CpuArchitecture: X86_64
        OperatingSystemFamily: LINUX
```

This all seems to match [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html). But clearly I have something wrong. What am I missing?

For reference, the full template is [here](https://github.com/codeguru42/go-capture-api/blob/4-aws-ecs/cloud-formation/ecs.yml). I only changed some names in the copied version here. But otherwise it should be the same at the time I originally wrote this question. Any other differences are due to pushing changes to my branch to try them out.

Comment: Sadly its not clear what you are doing. Your error says that your service is called `MyService` but your CFN template has definition of a different service. In other words, your question does not represent your real code.

Comment: @Marcin That is an editing error as I tried to obfuscate my actual naming. It is fixed now.

Comment: If this is your actual code, then there is nothing wrong with it. The error is caused by something outside of this code, or different code that you use. The code perfectly fine and it works (I run it).

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the response. I've checked and double checked everything I can think of and can't find anything that is wrong. Any ideas what else I should check?

Comment: The code is fine. Does this happen only for this template? What about if you try running your ecs task manually in AWS console using the same role?

Comment: @Marcin I am able to deploy two other templates with the same role. These are for updating the role itself and for creating an ECR repo.

Comment: @Marcin Also, I added a link to the current version of the template on my feature branch on github. If you have time to take a look, that would be great. But no worries if you don't.

Comment: @Marcin Would you mind providing the full command you used to deploy this template?

Comment: Now I can see the error when using the code from github. Interesting.

Comment: @Marcin So the biggest difference I see between my template on github and what I posted here is that I left out the VPC, Security Group, and Subnet from my post here. Is it possible that any of those cause the problem? How would I trouble shoot this?

Comment: For completeness, I added a `Path` to my template code in the question since this is what caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the github version you have `Path: /gocapture/`, while in SO you don't have it. Thus as I wrote earlier, your code in question is different then your actual code.

I modify your code to remove `Path: /gocapture/`.

```
Parameters:
  TaskImage:
    Type: String
Resources:
  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: GoCaptureExecutionRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      #Path: /gocapture/

  TaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: GoCaptureTaskRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
      #Path: /gocapture/

  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16

  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: GoCaptureSecurityGroup
      GroupDescription: Security Group for Go Capture ECS Service
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  PublicSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: GoCaptureCluster

  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref SecurityGroup
          Subnets:
            - !Ref PublicSubnet
      ServiceName: GoCaptureECSService
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition

  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: GoCaptureContainer
          Image: !Ref TaskImage
      Cpu: .25 vCPU
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      Family: GoCapture
      Memory: 0.5 GB
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RuntimePlatform:
        CpuArchitecture: X86_64
        OperatingSystemFamily: LINUX
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole
```

Comment: FML...the `Path` property is in fact the problem. I recommend that you remove the IGW and other pieces that you added since they don't have anything to do with the error I asked about. I might need those, but haven't got there yet.

Comment: That's what I get for removing shit from my code in a question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice IGW and other pieces have been removed.

Comment: I'm not exactly new here. I just missed that detail. There ya go.